# using SlidingMenu for android

Tags: java, android, slidingmenu

Im using [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) lib for adding my slidemenu. This work when i swipe the screen but how can I show the menu in an on click method? I've been browsing this whole lib but just can't find the on click code!

Comment: pfff.... just found that its the toggle method on your slidemenu -_-... searched for hours!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
toggle();
```

When inside a SlidingActivity or SlidingFragmentActivity (or any of the [others](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/tree/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app)).

Comment: +1 for being a few seconds faster than me :P

Comment: jeah lol.. just found that the hard way. Will accept this as an answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: btw.. im using the LEFT and RIGHT scrollview and want both sides to be controlled by a button. Is there an easy way to show the right side menu?

Comment: Check these methods, they're probably the ones you're interested in: https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/slidingmenu/lib/app/SlidingActivityHelper.java#L178-202

Answer (score 1):

This will open the menu:

```
toggle();
```